# File download with aspx, Symbols added to end of file

Tags: asp.net, download

I have an aspx site:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Download.aspx.cs" Inherits="ATP.Management.Web.Download" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

with this code behind:

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
 Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename={0}".FormatWith(filename));
 var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\" + filename);
 Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

*Please note that I am not really reading from c:\temp, this is just some test code.* This works very well, and the file transfers properly, but when I open the file in notepad, it seems to have the  `<html>....</html>` text of the download page attached to it.

Why is that happening and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Response.End()` after the binary write.